# NSDate format time with start and end in hours

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Is there a way to format time so that it shows up as
`19-Oct-2015 3-6 PM`? I know how to set day, month, year. I just need to know if it's possible to set the hours so that it shows a timeframe like 3pm-6pm or if I will just have to format the strings myself.

Comment: I don't think its possible because date formatters are used to format a date but in your case you want to show a period of time that includes 2 different dates (19-Oct-2015 3 PM to 19-Oct-2015 6 PM). Because of which i believe the time portion you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to format at least the time portion yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**NSDateFormatter** formats **NSDate**. **NSDate** is something which denotes single point in time. It seems like you want to define time with range ie. at least two different **NSDate**s. So, it might not be possible to do that with only **NSDateFormatter**. If both date start date and end date lie on the same date, you could use **NSDateFormatter** to format time and then get components of hour for two different date, then compose the string to have it like you showed above.